# How is g00gle making the OO blink like eyes?

Tags: javascript

So I was searching google today and notice the two 00 blink like two eyes. I look at the code but can't figure out how they've done it. I think is jquery or some custom js framework.

Pls let me know if you know anything about this. The only problem is I had to refresh the page several times (10, even 20 some times) before they blink.

I manage to take a print screen
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/282983/Screenshot.png

Comment: April fools ?
Google's or maybe... yours :P

Comment: Given that they've had a completely functional Pacman game as their logo, blinking eyes is *nothing*

Comment: Damn, you really made me go to the google page and wait for that blink... I should know better. :-P

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how google do it, but if I was to do it, I would use images of 00 with a z-index of 2.

Behind the 00 image you can simply animate the background using jquery to make it appear like they are blinking.

Just search background-animation jquery for the code to use.

Hope this helps.